# Log subscribe error in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, response

I need to log response status from the post request. However, I don't see how subscribe method returns this information. This is is my code:

```
this.http.post(this.url, formData, options)
    .subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log('success');
        this.getData();
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log() // here I want to log error status
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, you need to **`console.log(error)`**

```
   return this.http.post(this.url, formData, options)
  .subscribe(
    resp => {
      const dataFromServer = resp.json();
      console.log(dataFromServer);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle this, you'll have to get it in the first callback of `.subscribe()`:

```js
this.http.post(this.url, formData, options)
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      // other code
    });
```